# magento determine if user has entered shipping information

Tags: magento, checkout, cart

I'm hoping someone can help me hook into this.  The scenario is pretty straightforward:

A user has purchased a product and "views their cart".  The URL looks like this:

```
http://shop-local.mysite.com/mystore/checkout/cart/
```

This shows no shipping and handling in the subtotals section below (though it does show it in the details section above which is annoying).

Now, the user "proceeds to checkout" and enters billing and shipping info.  I have already tested, and once they have entered shipping info (2nd step on onepage checkout) and if they then return to view their cart, the shipping and tax info will show.

My question is, is there any way similar to `..->isLoggedIn()` to determine if quote has shipping address yet?  something like:

```
Mage::helper('quote/shipping')->getShipping()
```

or

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->quoteHasShipping()
```

obviously those aren't correct but something like that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try the default shipping address for that.Try like this :

Get customer default shipping information

```
$customerAddressId = Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping();
if ($customerAddressId){
$address = Mage::getModel(‘customer/address’)->load($customerAddressId);
$address->getData();
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();

if(empty($shippingAddress)) {
//do your thing
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, that does not work.  I have checked `sales_flat_quote_address` on starting the ecommerce process, and in fact shipping address record is present, even before user gets to checkout - just the values are null, but the object is not empty.

Comment: so you can check the values of the object. if they are null means shipping address is not present. if they are not null means shipping address is present.

Comment: Reena is correct. The billing and shipping addresses are added for each quote that needs it. When the user fills out billing and shipping address and continues to next step, then the  quote addresses are saved.

Comment: thank you David, you can upvote to show your support :) @OliverWilliams - please upvote and accept the answer if it helped